# Prevent unicode characters from turning into emojis (especially in gmail)

Tags: unicode, emoji

This question has been asked before but before someone marks it as duplicate, please hear me out.

There are certain unicode characters that will automatically show as an emoji in gmail.I've tried applying a 'variation-selector' but that hasn't done anything. In fact, when copying the table from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_versus_text_presentation),

[image: unicode characters with modifiers from wikipedia]

containing all unicode with modifiers into an email, it will show the following in gmail

[image: unicode characters with modifiers in gmail]

As you can see, all modifiers are ignored and it will only show emojis. The reason why I do not want emojis is to have a professional tone for emails. I really want the base+VS15 version at all times but gmail won't allow it for some reason :(.

This problem does not occur when I open the email on my phone.

Comment: The obvious and clearly better solution is to not use emojis / icons / hieroglyphics in your email at all.

Comment: It is not something you can do. VS15 is the way to tell you want the emoticon as "text". If Gmail is not listening the basic Unicode, you cannot do differently (and hoping google correct bugs is hopeless, unless it is something they want to show in next product, or you have good connection inside google, or you are a journalist (and the correct person read you article and such person realize that it is just a task of 30 min))

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi that makes me sad. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What question do you want answered? Do you want these characters to display with text presentation in the GMail web app (viewed in a browser)? Or, do you want these characters to appear as authored in the email message which GMail sends? Or, do you want these characters to display with text presentation in a Gmail app for iOS, or Android?  All these are different cases.

When I paste the Wikipedia table you show, into a GMail message composition window on a Firefox browser, I see the same thing that you show in your second example: the "base+VS15 (text)" row displays the same as the rows above and below. However, when I look at the HTML which GMail generates in the composition window, I see something very interesting.

For instance, the cell in the "base+VS15 (text)" row, "26A0" column, has this content (line breaks added for readability):

```
<td><img data-emoji="⚠" class="an1 CToWUd" alt="⚠" aria-label="⚠" 
src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/e/notoemoji/14.0/26a0/32.png" 
loading="lazy">︎&#xFE0E;</td>
```

**Note**: in the actual HTML, the sequence `&#xFE0E;` was instead the literal character `U+FE0E VARIATION SELECTOR-15`, not the HTML hexadecimal entity reference. It turns out that the StackOverflow editor seems to discard the literal U+FE0E character. I had to represent it by something to make it visible in this answer.

So, it seems that GMail chooses to replace the literal `U+26A0 WARNING SIGN` character with an `<img>` tag, which instructs the browser to display an image at the URL […/26a0/32.png](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/e/notoemoji/14.0/26a0/32.png), which is the emoji presentation [image] which you observed in GMail. However, GMail does not discard the `U+FE0E VARIATION SELECTOR-15`. That character is still present, just after the `<img>` tag.

When I send that email to another email program (I used [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/)), I see the table the same way as you showed in your first example. The "base+VS15 (text)" row displays the *differently* than the rows above *or* below.

When I look at the source of the email message I received, and look in that same cell of the table, I see the following:

```
=E2=9A=A0=EF=B8=8E
```

This is the two characters, U+26A0 U+FE0E, expressed in UTF-8 and then represented with MIME hex escaping.  That is evidence that the email message which GMail sent no longer had GMail's `<img>` tag, and again had the original characters.

So, do you want these characters to display with text presentation in the GMail web app (viewed in a browser)? I think GMail chooses to deny you that. They perhaps made a design decision that it was better to be sure users saw some form of each emoji, regardless of what browser or fonts the user might have installed, than to get VS15 text display right.

But, do you want these characters to appear as authored in the email message which GMail sends? I think GMail gives you that with no special effort.

It is more difficult to see what is going on with the composition window display of GMail apps for iOS or Android, so I am not going to attempt that.

By the way, I got this HTML by using the [Firefox developer tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), control-click…"Inspect Element" on the contents of that cell, then clicking on the  tag, and using the control-click… "Copy… Outer HTML" to copy the HTML, then pasting the HTML into a plain text editor.

Comment: Jesus christ, this is a great answer. Thank you very much!